# Adding transparent RGBA value to existing RGBA value?

Tags: colors, libgdx, rgba

I am generating masked images using `Pixmap` and I want to combine a transparent image with my current masked resulted. I would like the same result as I get in Photoshop with just a layer on top set to normal blending.

So when I am generating a image I first iterate over my masking image and when I encounter a black pixel I add a pixel to a new `Pixmap` with the corresponding color of the original. But I also want to check the the additional image that needs to be blended. If that image has a alpha above `0` at the corresponding pixel I want to add it's value to the value I got from the original image.

The best solution would be to combine both RGBA `int` values in a single line instead of sorting out the bits, adding the values and turn it back in a packed single `int` RGBA value.

Comment: How big is your image? I think this would be better done with a shader for performance

Comment: @Nicolas Images atm 960x960 but performance is not a issue. I can create a couple dozen of masked images in 200ms and just checking a additional pixmap on the same pixel coordinate for a color will not hit performance significantly. I only need to be doing this sparingly on user request, I suck at shader language and I am creating the masks anyway so I get separate images I can further manipulate.

Comment: So you're just asking about the best way to blend the two colors?

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, a normal blend but with rgba values. And preferably on a single line with the packed bits represented by a `Integer`.

Comment: I think you're looking for [alpha blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending). The wiki page has a short description of it (src OVER dst).

Comment: @Nicolas Thats an intesting read, I just need the outer cases as in completely opaque and completely transparent foreground image and then lerp in between them where `t = alpha channel`. Logically now I think of it. Is there anyway I can do the calculations while maintaining the packed colors as in a single `Integer`? Otherwise I need to unpack both colors, blend them and then repack the final color for each pixel that needs changing.

Comment: You need to unpack alpha and RGB. With bitwise operations it should not be a performance problem.

Comment: @Nicolas Probably not and will try this. However it are 10 times more operations then calculating the packed color value in one line if at all possible. And doing it a couple million times might help,

Comment: Hence the shader... if you add a little more info and sample images and results I can probably write you some shader script and code to go with it.